# Git repository where script is physically in another git repository

Tags: git, git-submodules, symlink, phped

I am simultaneously developing a composer package and app which uses that composer package.  My app is a git repository where the `vendor` directory is ignored, and I wish to make the composer package its own git repository.  My first solution was to locate the package outside of my app and use a [local repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path) which will create a symbolic link to this other directory, but my IDE (NuShpere PhpED) doesn't seem to support execution breaks (off topic, but if anyone knows how to make them work, please comment).

I've looked into git submodules, but I don't think this will work since the script is physically located within the parent script.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: This may also be too difficult from the IDE, but `git -C <path> <arguments>` runs the equivalent of `chdir <path> && git -C <arguments>`.